# Rails: bundler does not install the package. (bundle install package)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I started using bundler (which is to my eyes a pure disaster).

Now I want to add the Googlebase-gem to my app. So I entered "bundler install googlebase" in the root of my app. Bundler in fact installs several gems, but not Googlebase.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes bundler install only file in your Gemfiles.

Add your googlebase gem into and after a bundle install it's install.

Comment: omfg how stupid can I be... guess this is a RTFM issue, sorry for wasting your time.